# Express.js/Typescript: Error TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm seeing this in Phpstorm 2019.3 with a red lint under .send()

```
// package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },

// index.ts
const express = require("express")();

express.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
 res.send('Express App Running') // TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Response'
});
```

Are these the wrong type definitions or is something else at play?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `Request` and `Response` types in the callback are probably not the ones provided by Express.
Make sure you import the right types:

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("foo");
});
```

Comment: I'm doing this and still having the same issue, after adding a middleware. I noticed normally it imports the `Request` definition from `@types/express-serve-static-core`, and when this error happens, it imports from `@types/express`

Comment: Something may have changed in recent versions then. I'll test this out and update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use if you're using type module in your project

```
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Welcome");
});
```

But, if you don't (like me), it's somewhat different in express version 4.18.2, I use

```
const express = require('express')
const { request: Req } = require('express')
const { response: Res } = require('express')

app.get('/', async(req: typeof Req, res: typeof Res) => {
    res.send("Welcome")
})
```

Is there a better solution? probably. But this one worked for me.